# Using Image as Navigation Bar iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app consisting of many views. Each view is controlled by a navigation controller in story board. I would like to use a custom image as the navigation bar. I have created the image but am unsure as to the procedure of implementing this. The code:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"topbar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

Does not seem to work. I am placing this code in the view controller. Should I be using a different method of setting the view controller or have separate controllers for the navigation controllers? If so, how would I do this?

Here's the layout in storyboard:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Does this even get called? Isn't drawRect in the View itself, not in the ViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using iOS 5 you can do this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar"];
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

You do not need a subclass, you can use a regular UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this fits your case 100% but you can at least cover the navigation bar with an image like this...

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: navBarImage];
```

The image will be centered where the title would normally show but if it is large enough it will cover the entire navigation bar.

Comment: Yes, or the viewWillAppear: method.